# What those numbers, colors and lines mean?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

When I pass the mouse on crystal ball on lower left corner, I get this image.

[image: MouseOver on crystal ball]

What those number mean ?
What are the meaning of the colors ?
What are the meaning of the white lines ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers refer to the maximum score multiplier you have obtained on that field. The white lines are simply a visual indication of how high your multipliers are - one line for every 5x multiplier, up to a maximum of 4 lines (20x). The shaded fields are fields with challenge amulets.